# Query to fetch data with 1:N relationship in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, spring-boot, spring-batch

Database used: MS SQL Server

I have a table which contains the Parent Membership accounts and the child membership accounts in the same table in a 1:N relationship (A Parent Account can have any number of child accounts).

I need to fetch all the Parent accounts along with their child accounts using a single query and since my application (spring-batch application) processes these records each row at a time, I need to have all the child accounts along with the parent accounts on the same row. (I MIGHT BE WRONG WITH THE APPROACH HERE. I AM NEW TO SPRING BATCH)

I am able to get One Parent: One Child Account Records but then the Parent Account is repeated for every child account.

Database used: MS SQL Server

I have a table Memberships containing all the memberships subscribed.
Memberships can be of two types - Parent & Child.

Memberships Table - This table contains all the parent as well as child memberships issued:

```
Membership_Num|Membership_Type|Premium|Sub_Date|Pkg
MN001|Parent|1400.25|12-31-2013|BasePkg
MN002|Parent|1830.75|12-31-2008|BasePkg
MN003|Child|422.25|12-31-2014|BasePkg
MN004|Child|365.50|12-31-2015|PremiumPkg
MN005|Child|365.50|12-31-2015|PremiumPkg
MN006|Child|365.50|12-31-2015|PremiumPkg
MN007|Child|365.50|12-31-2015|PremiumPkg
```

MemberAccounts Table (So this table has the Account Id which maps the Parents to Child MemberAccounts that were grouped together):

```
AccountId|MembershipNum|MemberType
M1|MN001|Parent
M2|MN001|Parent
M3|MN002|Parent
M4|MN002|Parent
M1|MN003|Child
M1|MN004|Child
M2|MN005|Child
M3|MN006|Child
M4|MN009|Child
M4|MN010|Child
M4|MN011|Child
```

MemberDetails Table:

```
AccountId|MemberName
M1|Name1
M2|Name2
M3|Name3
M4|Name4
```

My issue is the 1:N relationship between Parent and Child accounts. There can be any number of child accounts under a parent account.

Sample Request for MN001 Membership:

```
- MembershipNum : MN001
    - MemberAccount : M1
        - Name: Name1
        - ChildAccounts
            - MemberAccount : MN003
            - MemberAccount : MN004
    - MemberAccount : M2
        - Name: Name2
        - ChildAccounts
            -MemberAccount : MN005
```

I am using Spring Batch and my application processes records one at a time. So, I need to fetch all the parent and child accounts as a single row to populate a JSON Object (i.e. the request) and post it to a Webservice.

Say, we want to process Memberships one at a time using Spring Batch. 
Can someone help me with the SQL query/approach in Spring-Batch on how can we handle this type of situation?

Comment: Sure, but what do you have so far that's not actually working, or needs "attention"?

Comment: To follow up with above, you claim *I am able to get One Parent: One Child Account Records but then the Parent Account is repeated for every child account.*. Where is such an attempt? And please show the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CTE and Dynamic PIVOT to achieve your requirement as below-

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@sqlCommand  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@MembershipNum  AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'MN001' -- Search MembershipNum 

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A.MembershipNum MembershipNum, 
    A.AccountId MemberAccount,
    B.MemberName Name,
    C.MembershipNum Child,
    'Child-'+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.AccountId ORDER BY C.MembershipNum) AS VARCHAR) C_Name
    FROM @MemberAccounts A
    INNER JOIN @MemberDetails B ON A.AccountId = B.AccountId
    INNER JOIN @MemberAccounts C ON A.AccountId = C.AccountId
    WHERE A.MembershipNum = @MembershipNum
    AND C.MemberType ='Child'
    AND A.MemberType = 'Parent'
)


SELECT  @cols =
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ( '],[' +  A.C_Name)
        FROM (SELECT  C_Name FROM CTE) A
        --ORDER BY A.Child 
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')+']'
FROM CTE

--SELECT @cols

SET @sqlCommand= 
N'SELECT MembershipNum,MemberAccount,Name,'+SUBSTRING(@cols,2,LEN(@cols))+'
FROM 
(
    SELECT * FROM   (
        SELECT A.MembershipNum MembershipNum, 
        A.AccountId MemberAccount,
        B.MemberName Name,
        C.MembershipNum Child,
        ''Child-''+CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.AccountId ORDER BY C.MembershipNum) AS VARCHAR) C_Name
        FROM @MemberAccounts A
        INNER JOIN @MemberDetails B ON A.AccountId = B.AccountId
        INNER JOIN @MemberAccounts C ON A.AccountId = C.AccountId
        WHERE A.MembershipNum = '''+@MembershipNum+'''
        AND C.MemberType =''Child''
        AND A.MemberType = ''Parent''
    ) your_table
) AS P
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Child)
    FOR C_Name IN('+SUBSTRING(@cols,2,LEN(@cols))+')
) PVT'

--PRINT @sqlCommand
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Output will be like-

```
MembershipNum   MemberAccount   Name    Child-1     Child-2
MN001           M1              Name1   MN003       MN004
MN001           M2              Name2   MN005       NULL
```